# Flutter Null-Safety Question: mismatch type issue

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

This is my function typedef:

```dart
typedef Widget ItemBuilder<T>(T item);
```

This is my class property:

```dart
final ItemBuilder<T>? itemBuilder;
```

This is how I pass this to my object:

```dart
itemBuilder: (Color color) => Container(height: 100.0, color: color)
```

This is the error that I get:

```
type '(Color) => Container' is not a subtype of type '((Color?) => Widget)?'
```

Can you help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The type error here is that the `itemBuilder` property is of type `ItemBuilder<Color?>?` while you are passing an instance of `ItemBuilder<Color>?`.

The difference is subtle, however, you are expecting a non-null `Color` while the parameter expects a callback expecting a potentially null `Color?`.

---

There are two ways to fix this.

#### Expect non-nullable parameter

If this is possible and intended, you should adjust your generic type parameter `T` to be `Color` instead of `Color?`, so that you end up with:

```dart
final ItemBuilder<Color>? itemBuilder;
```

#### Pass callback with nullable parameter

Alternatively, you can adjust the callback you are passing accordingly:

```dart
itemBuilder: (Color? color) => Container(height: 100.0, color: color)
```

Comment: I'm trying to migrate my package to null-safety and I used migration tool. (Here is the package if you need more context: https://github.com/figengungor/easy_dialogs/blob/master/lib/single_choice_confirmation_dialog.dart) The first option is not possible because It should be T. I don't quite get that how this is interpreted like this: final ItemBuilder<T>? itemBuilder; ----------- ItemBuilder<Color?>?

Comment: @FigenGüngör Because `T` is `Color?`. You need to make sure that `T` is `Color`.

Comment: The key part is `T` is set to `Color?` from code that is *using* your `SingleChoiceConfirmationDialog` class (and you haven't shown us the code where `SingleChoiceConfirmationDialog`is being instantiated).  It likely is being inferred from `initialValue` or `items`.